# sort table in angularjs with row values as function

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I have a table which the records comes from json objects, however some of the columns are filled with computing a get function:
`<td>{{get(a, b)}}</td>`

I want to sort the table, but the sort cannot underestand the column name for the columns with the get function. Any solution is appreciated

Comment: do you mean: `<td>{{get(a, b)}}</td>` ??

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to add a property with the result of the computation:

```
myArray.forEach(function(item) {
  item.foo = get(a, b);
});
```

then in the template you can use the [orderBy filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: can you give more explanation about the answer, specially how to use the orderby filter. I tried but it doesn't work.